# Merging 2 arrays based on a relational array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays:

```
$excel_arr = array(
         ["C1", "Title 3"],
         ["A1", "Title 1"],
         ["B1", "Title 2"],
         ["D1", "Title 4"]
);
$db_result = array(
         "title_2" => "Cell 2 Value",
         "title_1" => "Cell 1 Value",
         "title_3" => "Cell 3 Value",
         "title_5" => "Cell 5 Value"
);
$excel_db_relation = array(
         "title_1" => "Title 1",
         "title_2" => "Title 2",
         "title_3" => "Title 3",
         "title_4" => "Title 4",
         "title_5" => "Title 5"
);

usort($excel_arr, function ($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a[0], $b[0]); });
```

- `$excel_arr` is an array with the titles for each column in an excel file. The first cell defines the cell coordinate and the second the actual cell value.
- `$db_result` is an array containing queried values from a database. The key is column name in the table.
- `$excel_db_relation` is an array which defines the relation between the 2 former arrays. Which excel column is linked to which db table column. In this example they are very similar, but in practice there might be more than just an underscore that differs.

The cell coordinates in `$excel_arr` defines the order in which each value must be printed. To do this I sort the array with the `usort()` as seen above.

---

I need to somehow merge these arrays so that the resulting array becomes:

```
array("Title 1" => "Cell 1 Value", "Title 2" => "Cell 2 Value", "Title 3" => "Cell 3 Value")
```

The database array didn't return a value for *cell 4* and the excel sheet doesn't define a *E5* cell. So these must not be included in the resulting array.

---

I have tried `array_merge($excel_db_relation, $db_result)` and various combinations of `array_merge()` and `array_flip()` but no matter what I do I can't seem to merge the arrays with "Title X" being the key.

Comment: If `$excel_arr` defines the order, why sort it? That said, could you add an example of the final array?

Comment: @Yoshi, it's the first value in each array of `$excel_arr` that defines the order. It needs to be `A1, B1, C1, D1`. They are not sorted above. ~ Which final array do you mean?  The final result is already in my post at the bottom.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I misread that last array to be a intermediary step.

Comment: @Yoshi, your answer was great, why delete it? :(

Comment: I didn't notice the sorting problem with Romans answer, so I thought it's better than mine, and wanted to reduce noise ;)

Comment: @Yoshi, I believe his answer is cleaner, but yours is still definitely useful. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `array_intersect_key`, `array_intersect` and `array_column` functions:

```
$result = [];
 // getting concurrent 'titles'(by key)
$titles = array_intersect_key($excel_db_relation, $db_result); 

foreach (array_intersect($titles, array_column($excel_arr, 1)) as $k => $v) {
    $result[$v] = $db_result[$k];
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [Title 1] => Cell 1 Value
    [Title 2] => Cell 2 Value
    [Title 3] => Cell 3 Value
)
```

---

***Update:***
Alternative approach to hold *the order in which each value must be printed.*
 Used functions: `array_merge_recursive`(to combine cell titles and values into separate groups) and `array_column` functions:

```
$result = [];
$bindings = array_column(array_merge_recursive($db_result, $excel_db_relation), 0, 1);
foreach (array_column($excel_arr, 1) as $title) {
    if (isset($bindings[$title])) $result[$title] = $bindings[$title];
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [Title 3] => Cell 3 Value
    [Title 1] => Cell 1 Value
    [Title 2] => Cell 2 Value
)
```

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't output in the sorted order. For example if `"A1" => "Title 2", "B1" => "Title 1"` then it needs to be `Title 2`, `Title 1`.

Comment: I've just taken your *resulting array* `array("Title 1" => "Cell 1 Value", "Title 2" => "Cell 2 Value", "Title 3" => "Cell 3 Value")` as equivalent. Ok, give me a minute

Comment: Yeah, after cells 4 and 5 are excluded, it just so happens that the remaining cells fall in order by chance. :) I should've made a better example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = array_flip($excel_db_relation);
array_walk($result, function(&$value, $key) use ($db_result) {
    $value = $db_result[$value];
});
var_dump($result);
```

But make sure that all keys exist beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
//...
usort($excel_arr, function ($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a[0], $b[0]); });

$result = [];

// traverse the *title* column in the sorted $excel_arr
foreach (array_column($excel_arr, 1) as $a) {

    // could use array_flip to speed up this test, though
    // this can be problematic if the values aren't *good* array keys
    $k = array_search($a, $excel_db_relation);

    // if there is a key and it also exists in $db_result
    if (false !== $k && array_key_exists($k, $db_result)) {

        // assign it to the final result
        $result[$a] = $db_result[$k];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```